# How to set a boolean in smali

Tags: smali

I have this line of code in smali

```
:cond_2
sput-boolean v11, Lcom/geo/main/MainActivity;->mLARGE:Z
```

I want to directly assigned a True value to v11

How do I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use const or one of its variants to assign a constant value to a register. In this case, you can use either the boolean literal `true`, or the numeric literal `1`.

```
const v11, true
```

OR

```
const v11, 1
```

Answer (score 6):

> const v11, 1

And here is some more info http://androidcracking.blogspot.com/2010/09/examplesmali.html